# Work with queue

Tags: c++

Made a program that creates a queue and writes it to a file but unfortunately it can only write numbers. How to make strewing type data recorded. I thought it would be enough to change the type of the "value" variable from int to string.but this is not enough.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
class Queue
{
private:
std::vector<int> queue;
public:
void createNewQueue(int amountElement)
{
    queue.resize(queue.size() + amountElement);
    std::cout << "System: the queue was created from " << amountElement << " 
elements!" << std::endl;
}

void initZero()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++) {
        queue[i] = 0;
    }

    std::cout << "System: the queue was initialized with zeros!" << 
std::endl;
}

void changeValue(int index, int value)
{
    if (index <= queue.size()) {
        queue[index] = value;

        std::cout << "SYstem: Ready. The element at index " << index << " It 
was changed to " << value << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "System: change error!" << std::endl;
    }
}

void createFile(std::string name) {
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open(name);

    for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++) {
        file << queue[i] << std::endl;
    }

    file.close();

    std::cout << "System: queue file write successful!" << std::endl;
}
};

int main()
{
int selection = 0, amountElement = 0, index = 0, value = 0;
std::string name;

std::cout << "===================================================" << 
std::endl;
std::cout << "1. Create a new queue." << std::endl;
std::cout << "===================================================" << 
std::endl;
std::cout << "Enter your choice: ";
std::cin >> selection;
std::cout << "===================================================" << 
std::endl;

Queue q;

if (selection == 1) {
    std::cout << "Enter the number of items in the queue: ";
    std::cin >> amountElement;
    std::cout << "===================================================" << 
std::endl;
    q.createNewQueue(amountElement);
    std::cout << "===================================================" << 
std::endl;

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "1. Initialize with zeros." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "2. Change the line item." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "3. Save all to file." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "4. Exit." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "===================================================" 
<< std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        std::cin >> selection;

        if (selection == 1) {
            std::cout << 
"===================================================" << std::endl;
            q.initZero();
            std::cout << 
"===================================================" << std::endl;
        }

        if (selection == 2) {
            std::cout << 
"===================================================" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Enter the index queue element: ";
            std::cin >> index;
            std::cout << "Enter value: ";
            std::cin >> value;
            std::cout << 
"===================================================" << std::endl;
            q.changeValue(index, value);
            std::cout << 
"===================================================" << std::endl;
        }
        //I am very ashamed that I'm asking such elementary things
        if (selection == 3) {
            std::cout << 
"===================================================" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Enter name file: ";
            std::cin >> name;
            std::cout << 
"===================================================" << std::endl;
            q.createFile(name);
            std::cout << 
"===================================================" << std::endl;
        }

        if (selection == 4) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

I am very ashamed that I'm asking such elementary things.

Comment: BTW, pointers are not portable to files.  Your best process is to write the *contents* of the data structure to a file.

Comment: If you want to use `operator[]` with a vector, you need to either `push_back` elements or use the `std::vector` constructor to construct the appropriate size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually enough, you might didn't change everywhere:

1.`std::vector<int> queue;` to `std::vector<std::string> queue;`

2.`queue[i] = 0;` to something like `queue[i] = "";`

3.`void changeValue(int index, int value)` to `void changeValue(int index, std::string value)`

in the `main()`

4.`int selection = 0, amountElement = 0, index = 0, value = 0;`

change to

`int selection = 0, amountElement = 0, index = 0;
std::string value;`

In other words, your code will work with strings just change the type from `int` to `std::string` where applicable.

btw, correct your range check `if (index <= queue.size())` to  `if (index < queue.size())`

Comment: Changes were made. But I have one mistake here: 
q.changeValue(index, value); 
"value" is no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "int" exists

Comment: I solved the problem. Change: 'queue[i] = 0' to 'queue[i] = "0" ')